# Call non static method after create object from static, will it make leak memory?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I've learned not to store context in variables because it might cause memory leak. So I surpassed context by inserting into weakhashmap. However I need to use also AssetManager.

So, is this code leak memory safe?

```
public class FileUtils {
    private static WeakHashMap<Context, FileUtils> contexts = new WeakHashMap<>();
    private final AssetManager assets;

    private FileUtils(Context context) {
        this.assets = context.getAssets();
    }

    public static FileUtils withContext(Context context) {
        if (contexts.containsKey(context)) {
            return contexts.get(context);
        } else {
            FileUtils downloader = new FileUtils(context);
            contexts.put(context, downloader);
            return downloader;
        }
    }

    public String[] getCodecNamesInArray(ArrayList<File> extract, String folderName) {
        String[] codecsArray = new String[0];

        if (extract == null) {
            try {
                codecsArray = assets.list(folderName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            codecsArray = new String[extract.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < extract.size(); i++) {
                codecsArray[i] = extract.get(i).getName();
            }
        }
        return codecsArray;
    }
}
```

Calling in activity:

```
FileUtils.fromContext(this).getCodecNamesInArray(list, folderName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it still leaks the memory due to your private constructor assignment.
If the context had not been set first, then the assets will retain a link to it.

1. You mean the **withContext()** instead of **fromContext**, is it right?

   > FileUtils.fromContext(this).getCodecNamesInArray(list, folderName);
2. The function **getCodecNamesInArray()** will not leak the memory but **fromContext(this)**
3. I suggest you to firstly mark the **getCodecNamesInArray()  to public static** then parsing **Context as an argument.** This way it is not leaked
4. In case you really want to keep current API, try this

> 

```
public class FileUtils {
            private static WeakReference<Context> ref;
            private FileUtils(Context context) {
                ref = new WeakReference<>(context);
            }

            public static FileUtils withContext(Context context) {
                return new FileUtils(context);
            }

            public String[] getCodecNamesInArray(ArrayList<File> extract, String folderName) {
                // TODO: Checking ref.get() return null

                String[] codecsArray = new String[0];
                if (extract == null) {
                    try {
                        final AssetManager assets = ref.get().getAssets();
                        codecsArray = assets.list(folderName);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    codecsArray = new String[extract.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < extract.size(); i++) {
                        codecsArray[i] = extract.get(i).getName();
                    }
                }
                return codecsArray;
            }
        }
```